# How to enable the Split-screen for Only Tablet Device, Not for Mobile Devices in android

Tags: android

Is there any Way to enable the the Split-screen for Only Tablet Device,Not for Mobile Devices in android.

Comment: `Fragment` is what you need: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments. `StackOverflow` is where you code something, research something before asking, don't just put a question here without any evidence that you are in a real problem.

Comment: Hey, As of My Research to enable the Split-screen/Multi-window Support for My Application is by Setting the "android:resizeableActivity" in AndroidManifest.xml file  to TRUE for enabling and FALSE for Disabling it. If we Set FALSE to the attribute My application will not working the Split-screen Mode. But in my case I don't want my application to work in Split-screen in Mobile devices(Phone Devices) only. I think now you Understand my Question.

Comment: Then you should edit your question to provide more detail, describe what you have found in your research so others can understand it clearly.

Comment: Oh and try my answer below

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to set `android:resizeableActivity` to different value base on the screen size. You should create 2 resources for 2 screen type like this:

Create `bools.xml` in `res/values` and add:

```
<bool name="split_screen_enable">true</bool>
```

Create `bools.xml` in `res/values-sw600dp` and add (for tablet > 7"):

```
<bool name="split_screen_enable">false</bool>
```

Use it in `AndroidManifest`

```
android:resizeableActivity="@bool/split_screen_enable"
```

More info about the screen size specific config [here](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As per your Answer I tried same you mentioned But In Same Value we Creating the Xml File then it gives some Exception  like Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [bool/split_screen_enable] res\values\bools.xml [bool/split_screen_enable] res\values\bools-sw620dp.xml: Error: Duplicate resources.And I tried to it in different folders (value-large,value-sw620dp). But I didn't find any Solution its reads the value from Values folder only.

Comment: Oh my bad, I've updated the answer, the postfix should be in `res/values-sw600dp`

Comment: What screen size of the tablet you are testing?

Comment: 2048*1536 XHDPI 10' Inches Tablet & also (800 * 1280 tvdpi) 7' inches

Comment: Can you show me your `app/res/values-sw600dp/bools.xml` file?

Comment: Values:
----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="split_screen_enable">false</bool>
</resources>
Values-sw620dp:
-----------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="split_screen_enable">true</bool>
</resources>

Comment: It looks fine, but did the tablet use the right `dimens` or other type of resources file, Or they all also use the default file?

Comment: Thank for your suggestion.For Tablet devices the values are get from the 'value-large' Folder. But in this case they Read values from Default Folder only. Any How From you I learn Something related to this.